# Angular 5 - How we can test the router.navigate([id],{relativeTo: this._activatedRoute}])

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I want test this function in jasmine, karma. what is the prefer way to test this function.

`function test(payload){
 this._router.navigate([this.result.id], {relativeTo: this._activatedRoute})
}`

I have wrote the spec test this.

```js
it('navigate to redirects', function(){
    let router=TestBed.get(Router);
    let spy = spyOn(router,"navigate");
    
    const payload: any = {
      event:{
        body:{
          result:{
            collections: 0,
            data: [],
            errors: [],
            errors_count: 0,
            meta: {},
            upload_id: "r1q3oFQfX"
          }
        }
      }
     };

   // console.log("##################id=",payload.event.body.result.upload_id);
    component.test(payload);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith([payload.event.body.result.upload_id])
  });
```

as well i created the fake class

```
class RouterStub{
  navigate(params){
    console.log("parames",params)
  }
}
```

and add to the configuraTestModule too

```
 providers: [
    {provide: ENGINE_CONFIG,Store,Actions,Router,useValue:routerStub,

    }]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let I assume that in your component you use (_router: Router).

So in your test would be adding these lines

```
class MockRouterService {
  navigate() { }
}

const mockRouterService = new MockRouterService();

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    RouterTestingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: Router,
      useValue: mockRouterService,
    },
  ],
})
.compileComponents();
```

The code above will help you to mock the Router service with the fake class that only contain the function that you want to test.
then you just

```
it('should call navigate', () => {
  spyOn(mockRouterService, 'navigate');
  component.test(abc);
  expect(mockRouterService.navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

or you can test even more specific like this

```
it('should call navigate with correct params', () => {
  spyOn(mockRouterService, 'navigate');
  this._activatedRoute = 'your route';
  component.test({id: 1});
  expect(mockRouterService.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith([1], {relativeTo: 'your route'});
});
```

Comment: am getting this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined
    at rootRoute (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js:7321:1)
    at _callFactory

Answer (score 0):

there is other possible solution

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    route = TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute);

  });
 it('should navigate to path', () => {

    fixture.detectChanges();
    spyOn(router, 'navigate');
    component.redirectToPathWithRelativeToParameter({
      value: 'your path'
    } as any);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['your path'],{ relativeTo: route});
  });
```

component code for unit tests covering:

```
public redirectToPathWithRelativeToParameter(option: any): void {    
    
    this.router.navigate([option.value as string], { relativeTo: this.route });

  }
```